# Бот не видит тестовое сообщение

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, бот

Бот не видит тестовое сообщение при проверки, но видит само событие.
Доступ в ключе и события включил:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Пишу ему тестовое сообщение:

```
for event in longpoll.listen():
    print(event)

    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:

        request = event.object.get('text')
        user_id = event.object.get('from_id')
        peer_id = event.object.get('peer_id')
        chat_id = event.chat_id
        msg_id = event.object.get('id')
        vk = session_api

        if request == '1':
        send_message(vk, user_id, '2')
```

Но, он молчит:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Событие он прекрасно видит:

```
<<class 'vk_api.bot_longpoll.VkBotMessageEvent'>({'type': 'message_new', 'object': {'message': {'date': 1621607099, 'from_id': 154845243, 'id': 1045, 'out': 0, 'peer_id': 154845243, 'text': '1', 'conversation_message_id': 1033, 'fwd_messages': [], 'important': False, 'random_id': 0, 'attachments': [], 'is_hidden': False}, 'client_info': {'button_actions': ['text', 'vkpay', 'open_app', 'location', 'open_link', 'callback', 'intent_subscribe', 'intent_unsubscribe'], 'keyboard': True, 'inline_keyboard': True, 'carousel': True, 'lang_id': 0}}, 'group_id': 185905428, 'event_id': '83737a0a8195f701875bec48cfb29d4f4f6f1586'})>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вроде бы тебе надо брать значение с event.object['message'].get('text') те у тебя словарь в словаре.

Comment: Спасибо. С каждым обновлением Longpoll'a, что-то до меняется.